# asynchronous UIImageView in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, asynchronous

I would like to know how people implement an asynchronous UIImageView loading, if you have it inside a custom UITableViewCell, I've seen quite some examples using GCD, subclassing UIImageView.. all of them must involves NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection. So how do people do this in a subclass of UITableViewCell that has an UIImageView in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good tutorial which explains asynchronous loading in general....

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

You can use the same idea to load your image view..

Comment: I'd actually like to have a caching feature in place

Answer (score 1):

Look at this category: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It's a image downloader for `UIImageView`. You place you're image view in your cell, and in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, just use:

```
[myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"example.com/myimage.jpg"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple and ideal way to do this is to do the following steps

1. Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check if the image is available locally load it, else fire off nsurl request to download it in a separate thread and show a loading indicator image.
2. On completion of request thread, store the image locally reload tableView.